# Keep postion Y when opening offcanvas menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an offcanvas menu and a container with content. When I scroll down the website and open and close the menu I'm tryng to keep the scrolled position on exactly the position I was at. Right now when closing the menu it scrolls back to the top of the site.
That is caused by some css styling I gave to the container to prevent scrolling I guess.

When I console.log `offsetY` then it shows when closing the menu `0` as offset.
So what I'm I doing wrong?

So what I have is this:

```
    mainHeader.on('click', '.nav-trigger', function(event){
                // open primary navigation on mobile
                event.preventDefault();

                mainHeader.addClass('nav-open');
                $('.push-content, .offcanvas').addClass('nav-open');
                var offsetY = window.pageYOffset,
                $win = $(window),
               $body = $('.container-fluid') ; // the content container
             // Block scrolling
                $body.css({
                  'position': 'fixed',
                  'top': -offsetY + 'px'
                });
              $win.scrollTop(offsetY);
            });

        $('.mobile-trigger').on('click', function(){ // btn to close menu again
                var offsetY = window.pageYOffset,
                $win = $(window),
                $body = $('.container-fluid') ;
                $body.css({
                 'position': 'relative',
                 'top': -offsetY + 'px'
                });
                mainHeader.removeClass('nav-open');
                $('.push-content, .offcanvas').removeClass('nav-open');

        });
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to make a class, for instance `.no-scroll`, and make the overflow-y property `hidden`. This will keep the content from being scrolled either direction and when you close the menu you can just remove the class. Also, by doing this it should maintain your current scroll position.

Comment: Yes tried that before with setting no-scroll to html and body tag. However with `overflow: hidden` instead of `overflow-y:hidden`. Changing that works indeed. Thx

Comment: @Meules Np, glad I could help.